# The original name of the file in the page title

Tags: php

Add the following source code on line 6 to

I changed it, but it writes the file name instead of the original file name

```
<?php
require_once "./source/includes/data.php";
    require_once('jdf.php');
    require_once "{$mmhclass->info->root_path}source/language/viewer.php";
    
$mmhclass->templ->page_title = $mmhclass->input->get_vars['file'];
    

        $mmhclass->templ->templ_globals['file_info'] = $file_info;
        $image_size = $mmhclass->image->scaleby_maxwidth($filename, 940);
        
        $mmhclass->templ->templ_vars[] = array(
             "FILENAME" => $filename,
             "MIME_TYPE" => $file_info['mime'],
             "IMAGE_WIDTH" => $file_info['width'],
             "NEW_RATING_HTML" => $new_rating_html,
             "IMAGE_HEIGHT" => $file_info['height'],
             "HIDDEN_COMMENT" => $file_info['comment'],
             "UPLOAD_PATH" => $mmhclass->info->config['upload_path'],
             "FILE_LINKS" => $mmhclass->templ->file_results($filename),
             "FILE_EXTENSION" => $mmhclass->image->file_extension($filename),
             "TOTAL_FILESIZE" => $mmhclass->image->format_filesize($file_info['bits']),
             "DATE_UPLOADED" => jdate($mmhclass->info->config['date_format'], $file_info['mtime']),
             "REAL_FILENAME" => (($mmhclass->funcs->is_null($file_logs['original_filename']) == false) ? $file_logs['original_filename'] : $filename),      
             "IMAGE_RESIZE" => (($mmhclass->funcs->is_null($image_size['h']) == false) ? "width: {$image_size['w']}px; height: {$image_size['h']}px;" : NULL),
             "VIEWER_CLICKS" => $mmhclass->funcs->format_number(($new_viewer_click == false) ? $file_sinfo['viewer_clicks'] : ($file_sinfo['viewer_clicks'] + 1)),
             "TOTAL_RATINGS" => $mmhclass->funcs->format_number((isset($new_rating_html) == true && isset($failed_image_rating) == false) ? ($rating_info['total_votes'] + 1) : $rating_info['total_votes']),
        );
        
        $mmhclass->templ->output("viewer");
    }
    
?>
```

Now, instead of the following code, say

```
$mmhclass->input->get_vars['file'] s
```

what should i write?

Comment: You haven't really given us a lot to go on. What framework are you using? What is `$mmhclass`? The only reference I could find on a quick Google search is Mihalism Multi Host, but that doesn't seem to have received an update in about 14 years so I'm not sure if that's what you're using.

Comment: Yes, I use exactly the same Mihalism Multi Host script